# Compiling C++ without terminal or SSH access?

Tags: c++, ssh

I'm at work and we have completely locked down computers. I have no SSH terminal on here. I have a lot of downtime and I mean a *lot* of downtime since I get my work done quickly. I'm doing school online while working and it would be great if I could somehow compile some basic C++ code when I'm studying.

Any ideas?

I remember there was a code pasting site where you had the option of checking the output of very basic C++ code. What was that site?

There has to be some way I can compile very basic C++ code, stuff like this:

```
class Teapot {
    int cups;
    char* desc;
  public:
    Teapot();
    Teapot(int c, const char* d);
    Teapot(const Teapot&);
    ~Teapot();
    Teapot& operator=(const Teapot&);
    void operator=(int n);
    void operator=(const char*);
    void display() const;
};

// Teapot.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "Teapot.h"

Teapot::Teapot() {
    cups = 0;
    desc = NULL;
}
Teapot::Teapot(int c, const char* d) {
    if (c > 0 && d != NULL) {
        cups = c;
        desc = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
        strcpy(desc, d);
    }
    else {
        desc = NULL;
        *this = Teapot();
    }
}
Teapot::Teapot(const Teapot& t) {
    desc = NULL;
    *this = t;
}
Teapot& Teapot::operator=(const Teapot& t) {
    if (this != &t) {
        delete [] desc;
        cups = t.cups;
        if (t.desc != NULL) {
            desc = new char[strlen(t.desc) + 1];
            strcpy(desc, t.desc);
        }
        else {
            desc = NULL;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
Teapot::~Teapot() {
    delete [] desc;
}
void Teapot::operator=(int n) {
    if (desc != NULL && n > 0) cups = n;
}
void Teapot::operator=(const char* d) {
    if (d != NULL) {
        delete [] desc;
        desc = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
        strcpy(desc, d);
        cups = 0;
    }
}
void Teapot::display() const {
    if (desc != NULL)
        cout << cups << ' ' << desc << endl;
    else
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many online C++ compilers this [article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/online-c-compilers) has a good list. Although it looks like `Cameau` is gone and `LiveWorkSpace` has been in read only mode for a while now. `godbolt` is the odd one out on the list since it really shows your the assembly output rather than runs the code.

Comment: Wicked thanks! This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for.